# How to decrease number of checks before the insertion that a particular partition exists?

Tags: postgresql, triggers, partitioning

The tables in the database are partitioned by week based on the timestamp of the data i.e. tablename_y2019w20. But when partitions were introduced, the postgres started taking too much cpu time.

Collection CPU usage stats by running

```
SELECT substring(query, 1, 50) AS short_query, round(total_time::numeric, 2) AS total_time, calls, rows, round(total_time::numeric / calls, 2) AS avg_time, round((100 * total_time / sum(total_time::numeric) OVER ())::numeric, 2) AS percentage_cpu FROM pg_stat_statements ORDER BY total_time DESC LIMIT 20;
```

showed that the bottleneck is that the statement `SELECT NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name=tablename)` from the trigger function (see below) which is executed every single insertion.

As an example, the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` of a bulk insertion of 18 elements which happens every second looks like this :

```
Planning time: 0.787 ms
 Trigger before_insert_data_trigger: time=253.374 calls=18
 Execution time: 254.161 ms
```

But since we only need to create partition tables once a week, all the statements are useless most of the time. But I cannot create the partitions from outside of the postgres in advance.

Is it possible to schedule the creation of partitions in postgres, for example, only every Sunday?

Here is the function and the respective trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION data_insert_child_date()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
                DECLARE
                    match data."timestamp"%TYPE;
                    checks TEXT;
                    tablename_parent text := "data";
                    tablename text;
                BEGIN
                    IF NEW."timestamp" IS NULL THEN
                        tablename := tablename_parent||'_null';
                        checks := '"timestamp" IS NULL';
                    ELSE
                         match := DATE_TRUNC('week', NEW."timestamp");
                        tablename := tablename_parent||'_' || TO_CHAR(NEW."timestamp", '"y"IYYY"w"IW');
                        checks := '"timestamp" >= ''' || match || ''' AND "timestamp" < ''' || (match + INTERVAL '1 week') || '''';
                    END IF;

                    IF NOT EXISTS(
                        SELECT 1 FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name=tablename)
                    THEN
                        BEGIN
                            EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE part.' || tablename || ' (
                                CHECK (' || checks || '),
                                LIKE "data" INCLUDING DEFAULTS INCLUDING CONSTRAINTS INCLUDING INDEXES
                            ) INHERITS (part."'||tablename_parent||'");

                        ';
                        EXCEPTION WHEN duplicate_table THEN
                            -- pass
                        END;
                    END IF;

                    EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO part.' || tablename || ' VALUES (($1).*);' USING NEW;
                    RETURN NEW;
                END;
            $function$;
```

And the trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_data_trigger BEFORE INSERT
    ON data
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE data_insert_child_date();
```

Comment: What version of postgres is this?

Comment: @Jeremy version 9.4.1

Comment: Are you using pg_partman then?  Probably the best thing you could do for performance is to upgrade to 11 and use the built-in partitioning.

Comment: @Jeremy, no, these are simply triggers before the insertion manually written in postgres. And unfortunately upgrading postgres is not foreseen in the nearest future.

Answer (score 0):

### Schedule?

You could schedule only using external tool like cron or pgagent and you would have to do so before you need this partition or make sure that nothing can insert data before cronjob or pgagent job (or whatever) is done with partition creation. Assuming that, like you mentioned, you can't make partitions in advance. But then you would still have to create them for all tables or somehow figure out what tables need them (like INSERT that day data into parent table and then move it to partition at the end of day or week).

### Check only at Sunday

You can limit partition check to just Sundays:

```
IF extract(dow FROM current_date) = 7 /*maybe = 0 in US*/ AND NOT EXISTS(..
```

But if this trigger won't execute on Sunday for some reason (no data that day, server down), then you won't have partition for that particular week once Monday comes.

### Optimize partition check

You can make that check much faster if you don't have to use `information_schema.tables`. On catalog with ~100000 rows in it (indexes, tables, views and so on) checking if one table exists takes about 100ms on my machine, while doing the same check on `pg_catalog.pg_class` directly takes less than 1ms.

```
--pg 9.5 and up
SELECT 1 FROM pg_class
WHERE relname = 'table_name'
  AND relnamespace = 'schema_name'::regnamespace;

--pg 9.4
SELECT 1 FROM pg_class
WHERE relname = 'table_name'
  AND relnamespace = (SELECT oid FROM pg_namespace WHERE nspname = 'schema_name');
```

### What I do

Personally I think that I would just create a few partitions in advance every few months. It is what we have at my current employer.
Of course upgrading to PG 11 is best, but I can see how this might not be an option.